# Google Cloud SQL lacks raster2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud SQL supports the PostGIS extension, but I haven't seen any documentation regarding how to work with raster data on it. To load raster data into a table, we have to use raster2pgsql driver.

In this sense, does Cloud SQL support it? Also, it would be really useful if it had out-of-db raster support considering we could store data in Cloud Storage and query it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## raster2pgsql

This a helper to make the job easy. It's not strictly speaking required.

> raster2pgsql  is a raster loader executable that loads GDAL supported raster formats **into sql suitable for loading into a PostGIS raster table.** It is capable of loading folders of raster files as well as creating overviews of rasters.

You can just redirect the output of `raster2pgsql` into a file

```
raster2pgsql > myFile.sql
```

Then run myFile.sql on Google Cloud.